# Most serious and significant attacks on Tor users have been done via malware. What is the state of the art technology to defend against this?

Tags: security

The most significant attacks against Tor users have been done via malware; Even when additional security measures such as "Gap" is used in addition to Tor. What is the state of the art technology to defend against these attacks?

Comment: Please clarify how this question is related to Tor. If it is not, maybe move it to the more general "Information Security" stackexchange instead.

Comment: Dear Rhin, Thanks for the comment. I edit the question

Comment: It's related to Tor through the NSA presentation that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a live CD, that way any virus or Trojans Horse are eliminated by a reboot, change your mac address in case a zero day tries to sniff it and don't use any add-ons.

Answer (score 3):

The best defenses against malware are, first, keeping your systems patched, and second, being wary about what you give permission to for running under your account or under a superuser (administrator/root) account.

An adversary targeting Tor users specifically may go after Tor Browser Bundle components.  If you keep your Tor Browser Bundle updated, you will likely not be taken over through the TBB by most attackers.

If an adversary first has an 0day exploit for TBB or other software you use, and second, is willing to take the chance of burning that 0day by using it, then you are at risk.  Think on your threat model, and make your decisions accordingly.

Comment: This may still be better in the more general Information Security stackexchange.